# Subtract rows then sum values

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, row, subtraction

I have this dataframe where I would like to perform some calculations.

```
aa = c (1,3,1,0,0,1,6,1,14,3,0)
bb = c (0,0,5,0,0,1,6,0,2,15,1)
ee = rbind( aa,bb)
df = as.data.frame (ee)
```

First I would like to subtract from the first value in the row aa the first value in the row bb ... 1 - 0 ... then the result add to the second value in the row aa ... 1 + 3 = 4 ... then 4 - 0 ... and in aa 4 + 1 = 5 and so on ...

The desired outcome is:

```
cc = c (1,4,5,0,0,1,6,1,15,16,1)
ff = rbind( cc,bb)
df1 = as.data.frame(ff)
```

Any ideas really appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to perform a difference of cumulative sums:

```
cc <- cumsum(aa) - cumsum(c(0, bb[-length(bb)]))
```

I added a 0 at the beginning and dropped the last elment of bb. Because you want at the ith element the result before substracting the ith bb

I test it:

```
aa = c (1,3,1,0,0,1,6,1,14,3,0)
bb = c (0,0,5,0,0,1,6,0,2,15,1)
cc <- cumsum(aa) - cumsum(c(0, bb[-length(bb)]))
cc
[1]  1  4  5  0  0  1  6  1 15 16  1
```

**Edit:**
Another way to do it (thanks to lmo) is:

```
cc <- cumsum(aa - c(0, head(bb, -1)))
```

Comment: Because these operations are associative and commutative, you can also do `cumsum(aa - c(0, head(bb, -1)))` which is a tiny bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
for(i in 1:10){
  aa[i+1] <- (aa[i] - bb[i]) + aa[i+1]
}

aa

[1]  1  4  5  0  0  1  6  1 15 16  1
```